# can I pass argv from main to execv?

Tags: c, exec, program-entry-point, argv, setuid

The `execv()` function expects an array of `NULL` terminated strings but doesn't take the number of arguments.  It uses a sentinel value (`NULL` pointer) to determine when the array ends.

The man page for `execv()` states...

> The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename
>   associated with the file being executed.  The array of pointers must 
>   be  terminated  by  a NULL pointer.

... so my question is....

I want to pass the `argv` from `main()` to `execv()`.

Can I be assured that argv that comes into main is terminated by a NULL pointer?
That is, can I be assured that `argv[argc] == NULL` or do I have to allocate my own `char*` array of size `argc` + 1 and put `NULL` in the `argc` index?

If I can be assured, is it documented somewhere?

Thanks,
~Eric

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The `argv` vector is always `NULL` terminated.

The draft C99 standard states:

> If they are declared, the parameters to the `main` function shall obey the following
>   constraints:
>
> - The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
> - `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.

Comment: Can you cite a source for this?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill From the standard, section 5.1.2.2.1 (see for example http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.1.html)

Comment: lol... I'd like to mark the comment from @Adriano as the correct answer since I asked for a source.

What needs to conform to this guideline?... the compiler?, the OS (Linux in this case), the shell?

Comment: And what if I called the OP's program using execve without terminating the command-line vector with a NULL?  Would the standard comittee come and get me?

Comment: @cdarke no, they're more subtle and they'll make your program crash someday in the future when you'll be in the bathroom...

Comment: @eric.frederich to be conform is a compiler's duty. The way arguments are passed to the _executable_ may be different from each OS - and actually it is.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I added a quote of the draft C99 standard, I dare guess this language hasn't changed (since this isn't a new requirement).